# Comparing a field with several values at once using meta_query (WP)

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm comparing the `trip_region` custom field of my `trip` CPT to the first element of an array: `$filter_region[0]`.

Howevere I may have more elements in that array and I need to select `trips` whose `trip_region` field equals *any* of these elements. Is it possible, with `meta_query`, to compare (with an OR, not an AND) a field to several values at once? Because there's nothing quite like that in [the doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query).

```
$get_trips_region = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'trip',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'trip_region', 
            'value' => '"' . $filter_region[0] . '"', 
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
));
```

EDIT:

Here's my new code, presumably closer to the solution but doesn't return any result:

```
$get_trips_region = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'trip',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'trip_region', 
            'value' => $filter_region, 
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    )
));
```

EDIT(2):

Replacing get_posts with WP_Query and using WP_Query's request property I see the following SQL query is being executed here:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_15_posts.ID FROM wp_15_posts INNER JOIN wp_15_postmeta ON (wp_15_posts.ID = wp_15_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_15_posts.post_type = 'trip' AND (wp_15_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_15_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( (wp_15_postmeta.meta_key = 'trip_region' AND CAST(wp_15_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('47','46','45')) ) GROUP BY wp_15_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_15_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Relevant passage I guess is: `(wp_15_postmeta.meta_key = 'trip_region' AND CAST(wp_15_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('47','46','45'))`

Looks good to me, I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to compare with **IN** instead of **LIKE**. The `value` must contain an **array** then. 
[Here's](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) the doc.

```
$filter_region = array( 'Region 1', 'Region 2' );

$get_trips_region = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'trip',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'trip_region', 
            'value' => $filter_region, 
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't return any post now, no matter if there are one, two or more elements in the array. See edited question.

Comment: I'd recommend you to **inspect the SQL query** generated by WP. Perhaps the query can be seen already by simply `var_dump($get_trips_region)`. Otherwise you could replace `get_posts(...)` with `new WP_Query(...)` and write `$get_trips_region->request` like described [here](http://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/45390/wordpress-how-to-view-the-sql-query-generated-by-wp_query).

Comment: Sorry but I can't figure out why it's not working. All seems fine so far to me.

Comment: I suspect the problem relates to the fact that the 'trip_region' field is a "relationship" field created with Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use compare. Here is another WordPress Codex doc on [Meta_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query).